# After changing page when select menu is clicked it reloads my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

So I am trying to create a jQuery mobile application and I have some problems. Basically I have two pages. When a button is clicked I will change to page two like this:

```
{
    $.mobile.changePage('/Event_WebService/barManagement.html', {
    dataUrl : "/Event_WebService/barManagement.html?currentCityId="
    + currentCityId + "&currentBarId=",
    reloadPage : true,
    changeHash : true
})
```

and on the second page I have this in my html a select like this :

```
 <select name="currentBarCategory" id="currentBarCategory"multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
```

and I fill that select dynamically.

The problem is when I click on select my page is reloaded and I don't know how to prevent the select from reloading my page and I don't know why is reloading my page.

Comment: put the whole function in your question -- you just surrounded it with -- {  ... })